# Gridview compare to list and set value to gridview checkbox

Tags: vb.net, gridview, time-complexity

I have a grid view which has 3000 rows and one checkbox column and 2 textbox column.

I have a parameter list around say around 1700. it varies sometimes 5 or 10.

So I need to compare the list to the grid view and set the 1st checkbox column to true.

I use the compare and select method like below code which works well for a small number of parameter like 50,70

```
 If Paramlist.Count > 0 Then
 Dim row As Integer = 0
 For Each listItem In Paramlist

 Do While (row < gridview1.RowCount)
      If Trim(gridview1.Rows(row).Cells(1).Value) = Trim(listItem) Then
         gridview1.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value = True
         Exit Do
      End If
 row = row + 1
Loop
Next
End If
```

It takes a lot of time to compare and set gridCheckbox value to true when I do it with more parameter list and the application seems like it is hanging when the user uses it.

Could anyone suggest me a faster way with less time complexity / best practice to set the grid check box value to true in the grid view.

**[UPDATE]**
I have attached a image of the exception thrown.[image]
System.Invocation.TargetInvocationException

Comment: A gridview or `DataGridView` and is it winforms?  Fishing thu the control to get at the data is usually slow - how did the data get in there?

Comment: It's a telerik radgridview